# Regarding withdrawal of a paper which has not been registered for conference

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I had submitted a paper for an IEEE conference. My paper has been accepted for presentation and potential publication. However, I have not paid the registration fees and do not wish to  register the paper. I want to submit the same paper to some journal. So, is it necessary for me to withdraw the paper from the conference by writing some sort of email or Can I simply submit it to some other journal without withdrawing it from conference? I mean what is the need to withdraw the paper if I have not even registered it. Non-registration would automatically mean withdrawal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some conferences will publish even without registration / payment (exceptions, special support, considered worthy etc), so you **have to contact them** to properly withdraw the paper.

You must properly withdraw the paper before you submit it to another journal as you cannot submit the same paper twice.

Comment: To see whether you can withdraw at the current stage, and if so the procedure for doing so, check any contracts you signed at the time of submission or acceptance.

Comment: And this is not the standard way to go. Likely the conference organizers and editors won't care, but you should explain for which reason you do retract the paper. It is still some work done at their side, at end.